# ICSharpCode.TextEditor: Folding / Unfolding XML Tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml, text-editor, icsharpcode

I'm using the **ICSharpCode.TextEditor** for editing XML files in an own project. Is it possible to enable **"Folding / Unfolding"** regarding **XML tags**?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you got to implement your own mechanism for folding/unfolding, according to this article.

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Code-folding

Answer (score 1):

For an example XMLFoldingStategy, see C# file [here](http://github.com/StefH/ICSharpCode.TextEditorEx/blob/master/ICSharpCode.TextEditor/Project/Src/Document/FoldingStrategy/XmlFoldingStrategy.cs).

Comment: I am trying to find out how I can call a method to collapse/outline all XML nodes. Something like the option "View->Fold/UnFold All" from the Notepad++ tool. 
By the way, thanks for developing the XmlFoldingStrategy class!